# Qt и с++ ломает ком порты в Ubuntu

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, драйвер, com-port

Есть промышленный компьютер у которого на метеринке 6 компортов. Проверяю стандартными средствами линукса, то есть cat и echo. Так же у меня есть устройство где я могу посмотреть что мне пришло , т.е терминал на другом конце провода. При включении компьютера после установки драйвера cat и есho работают отлично, но стоит мне запустить приложение на c++ c использованием библиотеки qserialport не работает не приложение ни cat и echo. Драйвер просто умирает. Точнее драйвер остается жив но настройки почему то сбиваются. Вернуть к жизни получается только по средствам дополнительного по поставляемого с драйвером. Поведение мне совсем не понятно. Код приведенный ниже:

```
void comPort::connectPort() {
port.setPortName(settings.name);
if (port.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
port.setBaudRate(settings.baudRate);
port.setDataBits(settings.dataBits);
port.setParity(settings.parity);
port.setStopBits(settings.stopBits);
port.setFlowControl(settings.flowControl);
if (port.isOpen()) qDebug() << "Port is Open";
} else {
  port.close();
qDebug() << port.errorString().toLocal8Bit();
}
}

void comPort::writeData(QByteArray data) {
if (port.isOpen())
  port.write(data);
else
  qDebug() << "port is close";
}

unsigned char *comPort::read(int size) {
QByteArray data;
data.append(port.readAll());
qDebug() << data.toHex();  
}
```

Код настолько примитивен что в нем не возможно ошибиться , сразу отвечу на вопрос что в диструкторе я закрываю порт и очищаю всю память.Так же пробовал просто открывать порт без каких либо настроек, но не нашел если это сделать без настроек то какие возьмет компилятор или проигнорирует настройки и просто пульнет в порт. Может быть кто то встречался с данной проблемой , буду крайне признателен

Comment: драйвер порта какой? некоторые  виснут при установке setFlowControl и и прочего. попробуй не устанавливать параметры

Comment: @eri Пробовал вообще не передавать никакие параметры , только открыл порт и записал в него, так же пробовал без setFlowControl но с установкой всех остальных параметров,результат один и тот же, просто я нахожусь в сильном недоумении как я могу сломать драйвер с высокоуровневого языка совсем  не залазя в память

Comment: просто ком порт это не всегда rs232 и некоторые драйвера не любят лишних ioctl

Comment: попробуй работать через файловый ридер, видать ресет шлет

Comment: @eri по поводу 232 это понятно но он включаеться на уровне биоса , тут я согласен. А поповоду ридера не совсем понял, просто писать без подключения qserialport?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Встречалась мне эта проблема. Суть в том, что сначала порт надо настроить, а потом его открывать. Попробуйте так:

```
port.setPortName(settings.name);
port.setBaudRate(settings.baudRate);
port.setDataBits(settings.dataBits);
port.setParity(settings.parity);
port.setStopBits(settings.stopBits);
port.setFlowControl(settings.flowControl);
if (port.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite)) {
    if (port.isOpen()) qDebug() << "Port is Open";
} else {
    port.close();
    qDebug() << port.errorString().toLocal8Bit();
}
```

Причем, что удивительно, в Windows Ваш код будет работать и не важно сначала Вы открываете порт, а потом его настраиваете или наоборот. А вот в Linux не так: строго сначала настроить, потом открыть. Вот тебе и кроссплатформенность Qt.

Comment: Спасибо ,я так и сделал но не успел написать ответ, но надеюсь ваш ответ поможет кому то и он не потратит на это столько сил как я !

Comment: @jNX У меня вначале вообще шок был. Код отладил под Windows, все работает. Пошел в Linux (Raspberry Pi + Raspbian) - ломается и непонятно в чем дело. Со средствами отладки проблема. Провозился полдня пока нашел в чем дело.

Answer (score 0):

Если cat работает и не нужно устанавливать скорость на порт, то можно [QFile](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html) использовать.

Там есть сигнал [readyRead](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead) которым можно читать данные по мере поступления.